# How to include vue dependency using CDN?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, kendo-asp.net-mvc, scriptbundle

I have to include https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue2-daterange-picker in my project made with Kendo, Vue, .Net, Angular and jQuery(Yes it's a lot).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-daterange-picker@0.5.1/dist/vue2-daterange-picker.umd.min.js"></script>
```

I am including it via this in my scripts and when I try to use, it throws error **Uncaught ReferenceError: DateRangePicker is not defined**.

I have even declared it in my js file

```
Vue.component('date-range-picker', DateRangePicker)
```

How to resolve this?

I am also using `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle())` but I am unable to add the dependency through that also.

Comment: This is because no such string `DateRangePicker` inside this script. Maybe, you need another script?

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/Innologica/vue2-daterange-picker/tree/master/docs) says. This script is installed via `npm` or `yarn` which means you need some kind of bundler, like webpack to build your dependencies and your scripts (e.g. into one file).

Fact that you're using jQuery, KendoUI, Vue and Angular and not using any bundler is a little weird. It seems that if you want to use `vue2-datepicker-range` you'll need to use bundler of some sort.

Comment: I am using ScriptBundle via the statement `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle`. But I am unable to add the dependency through that also

Comment: As far as I know ScriptBundle only merges files, does nothing like building or transpiling - so it's not goot. I should say "Build system" instead of "bundler" in my answer.